# CGRectContainsPoint() isn't returning TRUE even though the rect contains the point?

Tags: objective-c, tracking, uitouch, cgrect

I have a UIView with a UIImageView inside it. When someone tries to drag the image view, the image view should follow the person's finger. Below is the code from the UIView's class.

```
- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];


    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(self.thumb.frame, touchPoint))

        self.thumb.center = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, self.thumb.center.y);

return YES;
```

}

When I start tracking by placing my finger on the imageView and trying to move it, nothing happens. From NSLogging, I figured out that the if statement was never satisfied.

However, when I start tracking outside of the imageView and drag my finger to the imageView, the image view will then  follow my finger.

Why doesn't CGRectContainsPoint() work when my finger starts on the image view?

Comment: Is `self.thumb` a direct subview of `self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

`self` is not a view (usually), it is a view controller.

Note that also assumes self.view is the superview of self.thumb. If not, more generally, you can use:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[self.thumb superview]];
```

Comment: but in this case, self is a UIView. (self.view didn't compile).

Comment: and the image view was already a subview of the UIView, so [self.thumb superview] didn't do anything either...

Answer (score 0):

How is touch being defined? 
I have been using the following (within the standard touchesBegan or touchesMoved), though self is a ViewController.

```
UITouch *touch = [[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I actually figured out the problem: I had userInteractionEnabled set to YES which didn't allow the touch event to reach the view. Sorry, I meant to delete this post, but I must have overlooked it.

Comment: @Mahir For which object did you set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`?

Comment: @Mahir sorry I meant `YES` :)